# How can I add the text input before the closing script tag in my textarea?

Tags: javascript

I am using rsform pro and want to make it easy for my client to add blackout dates to the javascript calendar.  I have created a text input box that will transfer the user input to a textarea. Here is what I have so far:

```
function transfer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txtT").value;
    document.getElementById("JS").value += '\n' + 'if(param1.indexOf(\'' + x + '\') === 0) \n\{ \n alert("We are almost booked up for this day.  Please call xxx-xxx-xxxx to make reservations."); \n return false; \n\}\n'
};
```

and here is the content of the textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rsfp_onSelectDate(param1)
    {
if(param1.indexOf('Sunday') === 0)
{
    alert("Sorry.  We are closed on Sundays & Mondays.");
    return false;
}
    if(param1.indexOf('Monday') === 0)
{
    alert("Sorry.  We are closed on Sundays & Mondays.");
    return false;
}    
else return true;
}
</script>
```

What I want to do is onClick transfer this to the line before else return true.

Is this possible?

Comment: `if (/^(sunday|monday)/i.test(param1)) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BSUK/)

```
function transfer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txtT").value;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("JS");
    var toappend = '\n' + 'if(param1.indexOf(\'' + x + '\') === 0) \n\{ \n alert("We are almost booked up for this day.  Please call xxx-xxx-xxxx to make reservations."); \n return false; \n\}\n';
    var reg = /(?=else return true)/;
    var oldtext = textarea.value;
    var arr = oldtext.split(reg);
    var newtext = arr[0] + toappend + arr[1];
    textarea.value = newtext
};
```